# Is the usage of 'By' and 'So' in the following sentences correct?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

> Our Primi Minister, Sri Narendra Modi, has set a deadline to fulfil
>   Gandhiji’s vision of Clean India, which is **by** Gandhiji’s 150th
>   birth anniversary in 2019. As citizens of India, it is our
>   responsibility to help fulfil this vision. So, there is an immense
>   need to give more importance to the sanitation and hygiene of our
>   surroundings and **so** to care for the scavengers.

1. Mahatma Gandhi's 150th birth anniversary is on October 2nd, 2019. So, before that date, the govt of India is planning to bring the 'clean India' campaign to an end by achieving its objectives.(cleaning is not going to end, but the campaign would). So, Can I use '*by' the deadline*?
2. The objective of the third sentence is to tell that care for the scavengers is as equally important as the 'clean India' campaign. I want to know if my usage of the highlighted 'so' in the sentence is correct.

please help

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the usage of "by"- I feel it may sound smoother and less vague to use "that deadline being".

> Our Prime Minister, Sri Narendra Modi, has set a deadline to fulfill Gandhiji’s vision of Clean India, **that deadline being** Gandhiji’s 150th birth anniversary in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

> "**[By](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/by)**" as a preposition can mean "not later than; at or
>   before".

So, the deadline to fulfil Gandhiji’s vision of Clean India is ***before*** Gandhiji’s 150th birth anniversary in 2019, or ***exactly on October 2nd 2019, but not later than that.***

> "**[So](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so)**" as an adverb means here either "in a manner or way indicated or suggested —often used as a substitute for a preceding
>   clause" or "in the same manner or way, also".

So, there is an immense need to give more importance to the sanitation and hygiene of our surroundings and so (=***also/ in the same manner***) to care for the scavengers.

Answer (score 0):

You could leave out "which is" and the preceding comma in the first sentence:

> Our Prime Minister, Sri Narendra Modi, has set a deadline to fulfill
>   Gandhiji’s vision of Clean India by Gandhiji’s 150th birth anniversary
>   in 2019.

As I understand it, the celebration (which may last for a period of time--weeks or months) is the time when the clean-up campaign ends.
"so" in the second sentence doesn't communicate your meaning, but you have already said it:

> So, there is an immense need to give more importance to the sanitation
>   and hygiene of our surroundings and, *equally important,* to care for
>   the scavengers.

Note a couple of typos corrected in the first sentence.

Comment: You have made the first sentence simpler and it sounds much better now. I think **also** could replace 'so' in the bottom half of the second sentence, as in **so there is an immense need to give more importance to the sanitation and hygiene of our surroundings, and also to care for the scavengers** where 'also' conveys your sense of 'equally important', especially  because 'immense need' is already present in the top half of that sentence.

Comment: I'd change _so_ to _thus_, but at this point it's really style.

Comment: Giving utmost importance to clean surroundings doesn't **lead to** benefit of scavengers, whether human or animal, who depend on waste-filled environment for survival, and would therefore need to be rehabilitated if city becomes clean. Hence 'so' and 'thus' may be misleading by giving the confusing impression of a cause and effect link between the 2 parts of the sentence. Would you write **how can we stamp out doping in sport and SO eliminate match fixing?** OP gives the clue by saying "equally important" while explaining the question. That's why I suggested the replacement of 'so' with also.